# Dynamic URL from database and MVC in JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, dynamic-url

I am learning JAVA and Spring Framework. I wanted to know that is it possible in java to create Dynamic URL in spring framework using values from url and fetching from database.

I am trying to make URL Shortner in Java and I will need to lookup for url's short code in my database and as we all know, url shortner will look like "url/ShorTCode" and my script will look for "ShorTCode" keyword in database and will redirect to associated weblink.

So I wanted to know that is it even possible in JAVA and Spring? And one more thing, if I make something like this "url/yt/VIdeoCode" or "url/fb/UserProfile"

So it will look at yt object which will redirect to youtube link only and fb object which will redirect to facebook user profile.

I want to clarify that I am still learning JAVA, JSP and Spring but I want to keep this thing in my mind while I am learning so I can focus on some particular things.

Thank you all fro helping me.

Comment: you can store some part of `URL` in database not whole URL, because `controller details` and other will be always `static` so as per `user request the url will be changed` so you can load that dynamic data form DB and make the `URL` dynamic.

Comment: Yes, and that's what I want to learn that how can I call it dynamically from database. "yt" and "fb" will be my controller but when its not calling from controller then I will need to load directly  from database and that I want to learn.

Comment: for that you ll need service that ll fetch data from DB and when you don't want to call that controller then call the service or call service in other special controller that ll give you data of url then you can go to that URL that makes it dynamic.

Comment: so can you provide simple example or link to the example?

Comment: ok i ll post it but i need some time, i ll post you after some time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how your controller could respond with a dynamic redirect, the answer is either:
(1) Have the controller return a "redirect:" result instead of view name. It must be followed with an *absolute* url, and behavior might depend on your spring version and configuration, but basically it looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public String myMethod(){
   String url=... // database lookup, e.g. "http://myUrl"
   return "redirect:"+url;
}
```

(2) Less elegant but sometimes useful: get direct access to the response. If your controller method has a parameter of type HttpServletResponse spring will automatically inject it. So:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public String myMethod(HttpServletResponse resp){
   ...
   response.sendRedirect(...)
}
```